# iOS - app store version behaving differently to locally installed version

Tags: ios, rest, app-store, installation, asihttprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASIHTTPRequest begins but never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934231/asihttprequest-begins-but-never-ends)

I've just had my first iOS app approved in the app store which I was very pleased about, only to be very disappointed to find it's not working as expected when installed from the app store.  The app uses ASIHTTPRequest to call a REST web service over HTTP/HTTPS and return data via JSON.  I've never had any issues with this while testing the app on the simulator/iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad - data is returned fine and if there is a network issue then the request times out gracefully.  However in the version downloaded from the app store, the user is able to login and perform a few basic requests but once they request anything further, or attempt to download a file, it just sits waiting and never times out.  It's as if the request is not even sent because my server shows no record of the HTTP request (using WireShark).

Has anybody experienced similar differences/problems with their app in the app store vs running the app from a locally installed version?

Comment: Have you tried running non-debug builds locally? Xcode's "Run" function always installs debug builds by default.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your response.  I've just realised I've not been running the app in 'Release' mode (still very new to Xcode!).  I created a distribution profile for my device which now lets me do this and yes when I run in 'Release' mode I get the same behaviour as in the app store version.  Do you know what debugging is available (if any) in Release mode?  And what type of issues appear in ‘Release’ but not 'Debug'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I hadn't tested my app in 'Release' mode, only 'Debug' mode.  Once run in 'Release' mode I reproduced the problems in the app store version.  I then found the problem was an issue with ASIHTTPRequest in Release builds - see following links :

[ASIHTTPRequest fails in production builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123975/asihttprequest-fails-in-production-builds)

[ASIHTTPRequest begins but never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934231/asihttprequest-begins-but-never-ends)

Once I set the compiler flags on the 2 files everything worked fine.

Jonathan