# NSUserDefaults working on device and simulator but returning NULL on device when installed via .ipa

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults, ipa

I am encountering very strange problem.

I am saving users email and a encrypted key with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`  for login to my webserver with my ipad app. This method successfully saves key values and perfectly working on simulator and also perfectly working if I install app to my device with USB Cord.

But If I upload my .ipa file for enterprise users and they download and install the app `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` doesnt save email and key and returns `null`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:userId forKey:@"user_id"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.email.text forKey:@"email"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:post_key forKey:@"key"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *post_email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *post_key=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"];

 NSLog(@"post_email %@",post_email);
 NSLog(@"post_key %@",post_key);
```

LOG ON Simulator and Device

```
post_email xxxxxx@gmail.com
post_key xxxxxxx
```

LOG ON ORGANIZER Device that installed .ipa file:

```
��May 17 13:31:19  xxxxxx[1590] <Warning>: post_email (null)
��May 17 13:31:19  xxxxxxx[1590] <Warning>: post_key (null)
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

```
EDIT FOR FUTURE REFEFRENCES::::::
```

Even though rmaddy's answer is correct for null values exact problem was: 
[ASIHTTPRequest begins but never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934231/asihttprequest-begins-but-never-ends)

and the answer was: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/asihttprequest/fw7PDcD2wKI

Comment: Use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Perhaps `self.email.text` is itself nil.

Comment: Silly question: can NSUserDefaults functionality be disabled at the enterprise level?

Comment: @rmaddy technically you have answered my question but that means it wasnt the exact problem, If you write the answer i will accept it.

Comment: @SpaceDust OK, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an object from `NSUserDefaults` you should use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`. `valueForKey:` is used for key-value coding (KVC).